# Encrypt and decrypt a password in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt a password  in Java and store into database in the form of encrypted.
It will great if it is open source. Any suggestions / pointers ?

Comment: The only suggestion is DO NOT USE ENCRYPTION. Use Hash... may be with some Salt.

Comment: @Nishant: do you have any example so that i can better understand.

Comment: Use http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/ for this task

Comment: See [tag:password-encryption] for why not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT** : this answer is old. Usage of MD5 is now **discouraged** as it can easily be broken.

---

MD5 must be good enough for you I imagine? You can achieve it with [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

`MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");`

There are also other algorithms listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA).

And here's an third party version of it, if you really want:
[Fast MD5](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php)

Comment: md5 is one-way hash only. You cannot decrypt.

Comment: +1.  @avs31586, you don't ever really need to decrypt a password.  instead you encrypt with MD5 and then when you check you always check the two MD5's.  Kind of gets you around the problem of people guessing your encryption algorythm

Comment: Oops. Missed the decryption part... Although when storing a password this probably won't make much difference, but I give my vote to Kal.

Comment: @:Ziyao..thanks for your suggestion but in our application we need to decrypt that password and display to user. do you have other idea for encryption and decryption?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but please *NEVER* use md5 to "encrypt" passwords. md5 is not secure, and is easily decrypted.

Comment: as Kal alreaady said, the question was to encrypt and decrypt a password. MD5 is just one way -> hashing.

Comment: hashing is one way

Comment: MD5 is broken since 2009: http://cryptocrats.com/crypto/md5-the-hash-algorithm-is-now-broken/

Answer (score 20):

Here is the algorithm I use to crypt with MD5.It returns your crypted output.

```
   public class CryptWithMD5 {
   private static MessageDigest md;

   public static String cryptWithMD5(String pass){
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] passBytes = pass.getBytes();
        md.reset();
        byte[] digested = md.digest(passBytes);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<digested.length;i++){
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & digested[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CryptWithMD5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        return null;


   }
}
```

You cannot decrypt MD5, but you can compare outputs since if you put the same string in this method it will have the same crypted output.If you want to decrypt you need to use the SHA.You will never use decription for a users password.For that always use MD5.That exception is pretty redundant.It will never throw it.

Comment: I don't know why, but this algorithm didn't work 100% for me. Sometimes the result was not correct (I compared the result with the MD5 crypted password returned by JDBC realm on Tomcat). This worked for me perfect: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/UseMD5toencryptastring.htm

Comment: @AdrianStamin Would you please explain what `0xff & digested[i]` does? :)

Comment: md5 is not secure (easily decrypted), and should never be used for passwords.

Comment: @theapache64
The digested[i] & 0xff ensures that only the 8 least significant bits of digested[i] can be non-zero .
0xff is 255 in decimal base and 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 in binary base
When you make the bitwise operation AND (&) with any byte it will ensure that only the least important bits  in the resulting number can be non zero.
Example:
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111  (255)
 &
00000000 00011111 00000000 01000000 (8000)
=>
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000

Comment: @alttag You are right. MD5 is unsecure. Nowadays people use salted MD5. The best way to store passwords is to let others do it. Like facebook or yahoo :)

Comment: @AdrianStamin : Even salted MD5 is a bad idea. Salting is good, but salting with a broken hash is still broken.

Answer (score 8):

[Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/)  can do it for you easy and simple

Comment: Working on something similar right now ... since it sounds like you DO need to decrypt the password at some point, something like MD5 won't work. I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: @JasonStoltz How to add salt along with Jasypt ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.security.MessageDigest` with `SHA` as your algorithm choice.

For reference,

[Try available example here](http://code.geekinterview.com/java/password-encryption-java-code.html)

Comment: your example is great. but it does not provide decryption . do you have any idea for decryption?

Comment: Use `Base64Decoder` [Example here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/376.html)

Comment: which package is required for org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Comment: What I have suggested is a very simple approach. But sun packaged files stricktly are not usable.
`String encoded = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode("text to be encoded".getBytes("UTF-8")); 
 byte decodedRaw[] = (new BASE64Decoder()).decodeBuffer(encoded);
 String decoded = new String(decodedRaw, "UTF8");`

If you want to go with another approach you can refer [this](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/security/java_cryptography_extension/StringEncrypter.java) and create a custom encryptor/decryptor.

Comment: What does Base64-encoding have to do with encryption and decryption? Nothing.

Comment: Base64 encoding is NOT encryption, and anything stored in Base64 can easily be known.  There's no protection in it. Do any of you work at banks or financial institutions that might have my money?  Dear god I hope not!

Answer (score 2):

I recently used Spring Security 3.0 for this (combined with Wicket btw), and am quite happy with it. Here's a good [thorough tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) and [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html). Also take a look at [this tutorial](http://springinpractice.com/2008/10/11/hashing-and-salting-passwords-with-spring-security-2) which gives a good explanation of the hashing/salting/decoding setup for Spring Security 2.