# JDBC Login/Register system

Tags: java, jdbc, authentication

I have made a log in and register system in java using MySql database (Connectpr/J driver). The username and the password are stored on localhost in a database. When I log the user in I check if the username matches the password in the database. The question is how can I keep the user logged in if he closes and reopen the program. Should I save in the database the currently logged in user? Is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to save the user info (user name or user id but NOT the password since its a security risk) in a cookie ([docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)) which is stored on user side so when he opens a new session you have to check the cookie and log in automatically.

Steps :

- user logs in for the first time
- save user info in cookie
- user closes current session
- user opens new session
- read user info from cookie and log in automatically

If its **not** a web application you can simulate the cookie behavior

Comment: How should I simulate the cookie behavior in Java? Thanks

Comment: The cookie is basically a file that is stored on the client side so all you need to do is to add this logic to your app following the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the username and password if you do not want the user to type it in again.  if this is a web application then you can use this [w3c cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

if it's not then you can save it locally on the users machine but use some encryption logic for this have a look at the following thread

[MD5 encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592010/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password-in-java)