# My JSP if-else statement is not working properly

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am new to JSP and I want to validate an HTML form using JSP, I am using an if-else statement in my code. But it's not working properly.

```
<%
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String uname = request.getParameter("username");
        String pw = request.getParameter("password");
        String pw1 = request.getParameter("confirm");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String idno = request.getParameter("idno");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
        String bgroup = request.getParameter("bloodgroup");
        String bweight = request.getParameter("weight");
        String lastdonate = request.getParameter("lddate");
    if (request.getParameter(fname) == null
            || request.getParameter(lname) == null 
            || request.getParameter(email) == null
            || request.getParameter(uname) == null
            || request.getParameter(pw) == null
            || request.getParameter(pw1) == null
            || request.getParameter(phone) == null
            || request.getParameter(idno) == null
            || request.getParameter(dob) == null 
            || request.getParameter(bweight) == null
            || request.getParameter(lastdonate) == null) {
        out.println("<div class='alert-message alert-message-warning' align='center'>"+
            "<h4>Alert Message Warning</h4>"+
            "<p>Some Fields Are Empty <br>" +
                "<strong>Please Fill All The Fields</strong>."+
            "</p></div>");
    } 
   else if (request.getParameter(pw) != request.getParameter(pw1) ) {
        out.println("<div class='alert-message alert-message-warning' align='center'>"+
            "<h4>Alert Message Warning</h4>"+
            "<p>Confirmed Password Doesn't Match With the Password <br>" +
                "<strong>Please Re-Type Your Password</strong>."+
            "</p></div>");
    }

    else {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        try {
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minutehelp","root","");
           Statement stm = con.createStatement();
           stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO donors VALUES(NULL, '"+fname+"', '"+lname+"', '"+email+"', '"+uname+"', '"+pw1+"', '"+phone+"', '"+idno+"', '"+gender+"', '"+dob+"', '"+bgroup+"', '"+bweight+"', '"+lastdonate+"')");
           stm.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println(ex);
        } 

    }

        %>
```

First I want to check whether all the fields are empty or filled, then I want to check whether the password and confirmed passwords are same and if there are no errors with these I want to send these data to my database table 'donors'. But it's not working properly and it always displays the warning message inside the if statement and data is not being inserted. But if I use only if statements instead of if-else, it always displays the first warning message and inserts data each time even if conditions were false.
I am very new to JSP, please someone help me here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your if statement is that you are trying to compare i.e `request.getParameter(fname)` and so on . but that doesn't exist. if you want to compare put **" "** this in your `request.getParameter("something")`

Also if you want to compare using variable in your case fname,pw,pw1 etc. try doing something like this

```
 if(fname==null || uname==null ... ){
     //do something
     }
```

Now to see if value of password are equal try doing this in your **else-if**

```
else if (pw.equals(pw1) ) {
  //do something
}
```

Also,you can modify your code like this to achieve what you want

```
if(fname!=null || uname!=null ...){

    if (pw.equals(pw1) ) {
  //your insert code put here 
    }else{
     out.println("<div class='alert-message alert-message-warning' align='center'>"+
        "<h4>Alert Message Warning</h4>"+
        "<p>Confirmed Password Doesn't Match With the Password <br>" +
            "<strong>Please Re-Type Your Password</strong>."+
        "</p></div>");
  }


}else{

  out.println("<div class='alert-message alert-message-warning' align='center'>"+
            "<h4>Alert Message Warning</h4>"+
            "<p>Some Fields Are Empty <br>" +
                "<strong>Please Fill All The Fields</strong>."+
            "</p></div>");


}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: And how can I encrypt the password here before saving it to the database?

Comment: Try this out-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592010/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password-in-java